# Что за элемент я наблюдаю в Dev Tools

Tags: html, css, firefox-devtools

На картинке видно, что есть какой то

```
элемент {
    left: 611px;
}
```

[image: html]
Скажите пожалуйста, что это такое. Это "оно" присутствует в разных браузерах, и на разных страницах.
Благодарю.

Comment: Так браузер отображает те стили, что прописаны выбранному элементу через аттрибут `style`

Comment: Благодарю, я все файлы перебрал кроме самого хтмл

Comment: Можно еще прикрепить ссылку на сайт, где вы нашли этот артефакт, и может это только у вас +_+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так браузер отображает те стили, что прописаны выбранному элементу через аттрибут style –
(ответ) CbIPoK2513

Comment: @Vasily, формально это Давид нарушил своей правкой :)

Comment: @Vasily, посмотрел - указание на автора присутствует - все ок

Comment: @Vasily, например, чтобы у вопроса был ответ, в данном случае лучше у автора вопроса стоит уточнить, в принципе твой ответ и комментарий примерно в одно время были даны

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае Вы перезаписали настройки стиля у выбранного элемента напрямую, через атрибут `style`.

Было:

```
.info_user {
   left: calc(50vw - 140px - 20px);
}
```

Стало:

```
.info_user {
   left: 611px;
}
```

Именно поэтому Вы видите что предидущие настройки пересекает сплошная линия (они зачеркнуты).